# Equivalent of Linux command `hostname --fqdn` in Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, fqdn

Is there a way to find the fully qualified domain name of a Windows XP box?

Being unfamiliar with Windows I would describe what I'm looking for as the equivalent of the command `hostname --fqdn` available in Linux.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can find it in the system properties ("Computer name" tab).

With the command line, you can run `IPCONFIG /ALL` and have a look at the "Host name" and "Primary DNS suffix" fields.

Comment: The two different ways give different results. ipconfig gives what I was expecting, but in the 'Computer Name' tab, the domain is different. It looks like a Workgroup name rather than a domain suffix. Is this a Windows specific thing where they are somehow equivalent?

Comment: In the "Computer name" tab, you should look at the "Full computer name" value; the "domain" value is the Windows domain (or workgroup) the computer is member of.

Comment: Ah right. Well there must be something wrong with the install on this machine, as it's only showing the hostname (with a dot at the end). Probably wouldn't have had to ask the question if it had been showing it as expected :-D. +1

Comment: Have you tried clicking on "Change" and then "More"?

Comment: No, unfortunately I am unable to as I don't have administrator credentials on these specific machines. The ipconfig command worked though, so it's all good :)

Comment: Just remember some systems are localized so looking for the proper line by nr may be better in some cases (it's line 5 afaik).

Answer (score 37):

There is no such option to the `hostname` command in windows. However, this should do the trick:

```
echo %COMPUTERNAME%.%USERDNSDOMAIN%
```

Or you can grep (under Windows: `find /I "string"`) for Host- and Domain from `set` or `systeminfo` or `ipconfig -all` name and glue it together elsewhere.

Edit: fixed Typo. Thanks Benoit

**Update:**
The variable `%USERDNSDOMAIN%` is only available when logged on to a domain... The DNS suffix you get from a DHCP server is not put into a environment variable (as far as I could figure out).

Comment: The second variable is "%USERDNSDOMAIN%".

Comment: %USERDNSDOMAIN% doesn't appear to be a variable on this system. Unless I'm doing something wrong: 
H:\>echo %COMPUTERNAME%.%USERDNSDOMAIN%
[correctname].%USERDNSDOMAIN%

Comment: Ach, forgot that pasting that would be horrible in the comments.

Comment: You can use **WMIC** to retrieve domain name: `wmic computersystem get domain`

Comment: This works only if the user is in the same domain like the computer.
I suggest NOT to use %USERDNSDOMAIN% for the FQDN of the computer.

Answer (score 18):

The command is:

```
ping -a localhost
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this from the command prompt:

```
FOR /F "tokens=2" %i in ('systeminfo ^| find /i "Domain"') do echo %computername%.%i
```

remember to use double `%` for `%i` if using this in a batchfile. e.g. `%%i`

A reason you may want to do it this way is: if your users and computers are in different domains, the `%USERDNSDOMAIN%` will not be correct when applied to your computer.
If you only have one domain and no child domains, then you can use the other solutions above if you like.

Answer (score 1):

vbscript :

```
' Print FQDN in lower case letters
' Volker Fröhlich (2011)

option explicit
dim Message
dim output
dim WshShell, objEnv
dim mydomain

' Read value from registry
function readFromRegistry (strRegistryKey, strDefault )
    Dim WSHShell, value

    On Error Resume Next
    Set WSHShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    value = WSHShell.RegRead( strRegistryKey )

    if err.number <> 0 then
        readFromRegistry= strDefault
    else
        readFromRegistry=value
    end if

    set WSHShell = nothing
end function

mydomain = readfromRegistry("HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\Tcpip\Parameters\Domain", "asdf")

' Get the WshShell object
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

' Get collection by using the Environment property
Set objEnv = WshShell.Environment("Process")

if (mydomain="") then
Message = LCase(objEnv("COMPUTERNAME"))
else
Message = LCase(objEnv("COMPUTERNAME")) & "." & mydomain
end if

' Write to stdout
set output = wscript.stdout
output.writeline Message
```

DOS BATCH FILE TO CALL ABOVE SCRIPT :

```
for /f %%a in ('cscript //nologo yourscriptname.vbs') do set FQDN=%%a
echo %FQDN%
pause
```

Answer (score 1):

This will also work and does not have the delay of systeminfo:

> for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %i in ('ipconfig /all ^| findstr Search ')
>   do SET domain=%i & SET newdomain=%domain: =% & echo
>   %COMPUTERNAME%.%newdomain%

Comment: Use four leading spaces to format your answer as 'code'.  The ubiquitous 'help' link is actually helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Another version:

```
echo.
echo Getting FQDN...
FOR /F "tokens=1-2" %%A in ('ping -a localhost -n 1') do (
    echo %%A | find /i "Pinging" >nul
    IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 SET "FQDN=%%B"
)
echo %FQDN%
```

Answer (score 1):

With PowerShell:

```
(gpv HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\Tcpip\Parameters HostName, Domain) -join '.'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to port Unix shell scripts to windows or just like to work on the CLI, have a look at **[GNUwin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/)**. It provides the common tools like cut, grep, etc for Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a CMD script for this:

```
@ECHO OFF

FOR /f "tokens=2,* delims= " %%a in ('IPCONFIG ^/ALL ^| FINDSTR "Primary Dns"') do set tempsuffix=%%b
FOR /f "tokens=1,2 delims=:" %%a in ('echo %tempsuffix%') do set dnssuffix=%%b
SET FQDN=%COMPUTERNAME%.%DNSSUFFIX:~1%

ECHO Server FQDN: %FQDN%
```

Answer (score 0):

use 'hostname' and combine with
for /F "tokens=3" %%I in ('reg query "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters" /v Domain') do set _MyDomain=%%I

Comment: can you please update the question due it is really poor in quality even if it may answer the question

Answer (score 0):

An other way in PowerShell

```
Write-Host "$(Hostname).$((Get-NetIPConfiguration).NetProfile.Name)"
```

Or as a variable

```
$FQDN = $(Hostname).$((Get-NetIPConfiguration).NetProfile.Name)
$FQDN
```

Sample output

```
ServerName.ad.example.com
```